# Set Page Top Left using Meta Tags - HTML

Tags: html, meta-tags

I want to set Top and Left position of MY Page using Meta Tags

Kindly suggest some solution

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you are looking for meta tags, as in `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`. You are probably looking for CSS and possibly a `<div>` tag:

```
<style type="text/css">
div.topLeft { 
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
</style>
<div class="topLeft">In the top left</div>
```

The CSS should probably end up in CSS file linked throught a `<link ... />` tag and you'll probably have other HTML including `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible.